# Java - Desktop.open() won't open videos or music

Tags: java, file, windows-7, desktop

I have the following method that is supposed to open the file that is passed in the associated program. It works for most files but if I pass any video or music file it prints `java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/8GB/Bruno%20Mars%20-%20It%20will%20rain.mp3. Error message: Access is denied.` (for example) and doesn't open the file, even though it is associated with Windows Media Player!

```
private static void openFileinAssociate(File toOpen){
        // Open it using the operating system/environment
        Desktop environment = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(toOpen.exists()){
            if(!toOpen.isDirectory())
                try{
                    environment.open(new File(toOpen.getAbsolutePath()));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured whilst trying to open the file.", applicationName, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
        }
}
```

AND here is the rest of the stack trace as requested. I can really post anymore of the actual code though, sorry.

```
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:77)
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:54)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:272)
at main.GraphicUI.openFileinAssociate(GraphicUI.java:1930)
at main.GraphicUI.access$12(GraphicUI.java:1924)
at main.GraphicUI$17.mouseReleased(GraphicUI.java:837)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I'm using Windows 7 and I have the latest version of Java...

Comment: Post the full StackTrace please.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Sorry for the delay. I've edited my answer as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) of `Desktop.open(File)` states, that:

> **Throws:** IOException - if the specified file has no associated application **or** the associated application fails to be launched

Try associating another application with the file in question and see if that works. Also, check the "Windows Event Log" to see if the WMP might be crashing when it's opened.

---

An alternative (which will work at least on Windows) is to use the [`Runtime.exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)-method and the `start [file]`-command to start the given file with it's associated application.

```
Runtime.exec("start \"C:\\Your\\Path with spaces\\file.whatever\"");
```

**Note**: When your path has spaces in it, put the path in double quotes (need to be escaped in the String). Also, since the backslash is the escaping character for strings, it needs to be escaped, too.

**Also note** that this method will open the "Choose appropriate application"-dialog, when there is no application assigned for the given file-type.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I've just associated VLC player instead of WMP and the files open without an error! I'm not sure how to check if WMP is crashing though - I've never actually figured out how to made head of tail of Windows Event Viewer... whatever is happening though, I would prefer it if I could prevent it! Is there a more 'bullet-proof' way of opening files in their associate programs?

Comment: @Andy short: no. Long: You can't even rely on the `Desktop`-class to work (across OS thought). Just catch the exception and give a decent error-message.

Comment: Really? `Desktop` is the only way? Isn't there another way using command line - I don't mind having two ways for mac and windows...

Comment: You could try the `Runtime.exec(String)`-methid with `start [yourfile]` as the command. I can't try it here, but it might work.

Comment: It looks like that command will work but I can't get it to work when the path has spaces in it! I'll keep trying to but meanwhile do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Everything works (even on Mac)! I've added the command lines in the catch statement for the `Desktop.open()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue. Don't know the reason, but found a solution.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL \"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(f.getAbsolutePath()) + "\"");
```